# Are Arithmetic operations evaluated in xml

Tags: xml

I have below sample xml,

```
<Field name="Test" value=5+5></Field>
```

Here, can the value for "Test" evaluate to 10? Can we perform arthimeric operations inside xml directly. Can anyone please help.

Comment: no, xml is text format without logic

Comment: There is no programming logic in an XML file. that happens externally through some app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's not XML unless you put quotes round the attribute value:

```
<Field name="Test" value="5+5"/>
```

It's quite common to use XPath for this kind of thing. 5+5 is a valid XPath expression and you can transform your document using XSLT 3.0 to contain

```
<Field name="Test" value="10"/>
```

by doing

```
<xsl:template match="Field/@value">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```